# Validating a model with 2 random effects and fixed effects of different levels

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, biostatistics

I have been working on this problem for the last little while and trying to write out the code to the below math/description for an ecological dataset in `lmer`, but I wanted to check with a few people to see if the code I've written out adequately reflects the math (which I am certain of!), as I could not find any equivalent examples in Gelman and Hill, 2007 or Zuur, 2009, and no one in my department has dealt with a a similar problem in `lmer` before.

For individual i of species j in lake k,

```
Hg_{ijk} ~ b0_{j[i]} + b1_{k[i]} + b2_{j[i]}*length_i + e_i
e_i ~ N(0,s^2_e)
b0_j ~ N(mb0,s^2_{b0})
b1_k ~ go + g1*chlak + eb1
eb1 ~ N(0,s2b1)
b2j ~ N(mb2,s2b2)
```

This model says that the Hg for fish $i$ of species $j$ from lake $k$ is a function of the species, the lake, and the length of the fish. The species effects are like intercepts – the average Hg for a particular species at average length (if the length data are centered) in an average lake – and they come from a normal distribution. The lake effect is itself a linear function of chlorophyll concentration, so that lakes with higher chlorophyll can potentially have higher or lower average Hg concentrations. The length effects vary by species, on the assumption that Hg concentration may change with size differently in different species. These length effects come from a normal distribution.

So in `lmer` I wrote it out like this:

```
M1 <- lmer(THg~Chlo-a+CenteredLength+ (1|Lake) + (1+CenteredLength|Species), data=data)
```

Is this right? Does this reflect the math I wrote out above?

Would this type of fully nested or partially nested structure be better?

```
M2 <- lmer(THg~Chlo-a+CenteredLength+(1|Lake:Species)+ (1|Lake) + (1+CenteredLength|Species), data=data)
M3 <- lmer(THg~Chlo-a+CenteredLength+(1+CenteredLength|Lake:Species)+ (1|Lake), data=data)
```

Also, if any of this is correct, when running these models, I come up with the problem that Length and Species have a correlation of 1.00.
Based on [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/random-effects-correlation-in-lmer-td821096.html), this makes be believe that the model without the varying slopes for length would be better.  Is this an ok way to conclude this?